# Issue with copyField when updating document

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am facing a issue with copyFields in Solr.

The relevant part of my schema.xml is:

```
<field name="ID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="product" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="product_copy" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<copyField source="product" dest="proudct_copy"/>
```

If I add a document like the one below:

```
Doc: 
    {
     "id":"1",
     "product":"prod1",
     "product_copy":["prod1"]
    }
```

when I update field *product* from **prod1** to **prod2**, I would expect to the document to be the same as above but with **"product_copy":["prod2"]**, but I get the document below instead:

```
Doc: 
{
 "id":"1",
 "product":"prod1",
 "product_copy":["prod1","prod2"]
}
```

Later If I try to update the document it will never update again as I get a exception saying multiple values encountered for a single valued attribute **product_copy**.
My question is: 
why its copying same value to destination field when I update the document and why its taking multiple values for a single values attribute?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you fill the field "product_copy" with your document? Fields treated with copy_field statements must not be set manually!

Comment: No!!! am not setting it manually.

Comment: Even not accidentally? Sometimes I encounter a like phenomenon when I reimport json exports, and forget to eliminate the copied fields.

Comment: No am not setting it manually.
I would like to mention one more point here.
The strange part here is if I set the product_copy to null before I update and then do a update then product_copy field will contain only single value that is updated value.
I am guessing each time I do a update it will copy value from product to product_copy.  If the  value is already present in the product_copy then it will add new value along with old value resulting in causing multiple values to be added to product_copy field.

Comment: What version number of schema.xml do you declare? in version 1.0, all fields are multivalued per default: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Schema_version_attribute_in_the_root_node

Comment: Its recommended not to mention the copyfields record while adding/updating the docs. Since because copyfields is taken care by solr. If you add the copy field it can hold maximum of two values as string array and the second string in the array will get updated once you mention the copyfield data in JSON.